# How to remove canvas_url from facebook app programmatically

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to remove "App on Facebook" block in my application by doing this.

```
$fb = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => <APPID>,
    'secret' => <APPSECRET>,
    'cookie' => true
));

$fbValues = array();
$fbValues['namespace'] = '';
$fbValues['canvas_url'] = '';
$fbValues['secure_canvas_url'] = '';
$facebookReturn = $fb->api('/151456581658184', 'post', $fbValues);
```

facebook returns ok, but the values does not change.

How can I unset this values other way?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that these parameters are (or should be) able to be set programatically... Those are quite sensitive fields...

Comment: @Lix This values are settable from api (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/)

Comment: Oh...wow...you're right! Scary...